# How to write data to a graphics card without using BIOS?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, operating-system, hardware

I want to make an (extremely simple) operating system. I am currently learning about graphics cards.

This is what I know so far (please correct me if I am wrong):

- A graphics card has two modes: a text mode, and a graphics mode.
- You can write data to a graphics cards using BIOS (instead of accessing the graphics card directly).

What I want to do is to write directly to the graphics card's video memory without using BIOS (because I want to understand how things work). So I have the following questions:

1. How do I know what is the base address of the video memory of the graphics card, is this
   done by probing the PCI bus to get the base address, or is the base address fixed (just like the COM ports base addresses is fixed for example)?
2. Are all graphics cards accessed in the same way, or do I have to create device drivers for all available graphics cards?

---

***Edit:*** I am using x86.

Comment: The simplest is to stick to VGA compatible stuff.

Comment: VGA cards have many more than two modes. For example there's huge difference between 16 colour EGA modes, 256 colour 320x100 "mode 13h" mode, and early SVGA modes, while you can write to VRAM directly, the base pointer and organization of VRAM is completely different for each of them. Also all graphics cards are different, you have to create driver for particular one, the only a bit standardized way was CGA/EGA/VGA standards in early PC era, and VESA (SVGA) did work on many cards, but since the 3D accelerated cards era you need particular driver for particular card (they may have VGA emulated)

Comment: In my youth I used *Programmer's guide to the EGA and VGA graphics cards by Ferraro*. If your environment allows direct R/W of the graphics controller.

Comment: If it is an "extremely simple" OS I recommend you stay with a text mode. I observe that my machines' system BIOS and UEFI use text mode. After you master that, move on to grahics modes.

Comment: Are graphics cards backwards compatible?

Comment: yes you will start with lspci or something like that to determine the base address, but then you need the register spec for the card, to tell the card to go into some mode, and also give you a window into the video memory as depending on mode the amount of addressable space for all the pixels can be less than the pcie window.  (flat memory space is an illusion)

Comment: Err... so that the BIOS/UEFI can use whatever you have plugged in?

Comment: start with the linux and/or bsd or both drivers for some card  ideally a simple dumb framebuffer mode not something advanced.  or even better, look at virtualbox, vmware, bochs even better, some emulated well known card(s).

Comment: Same school perhaps.

Comment: Modern graphics cards are all VGA compatible, though not necessarily 100% compatible in every little detail. VGA compatibility limits you to 648x480 with 16 colours and 320x200 with 256 colours, though it you don't mind using non-standard modes you can do 800x600 with 16 colours. If you want to go beyond those resolutions then you'll need to drivers for all the various kinds of video cards there are.

Comment: but vga compatible doesnt mean the register specs are the same correct? that just means they have some compatible modes.  same as when those modes came out yes?  or no?

Comment: @old_timer It means the register specs are the same.

Comment: you could just disassemble the bios that you find and that works for your card, and compare that to the documentation for the chip you are using

Comment: @RossRidge good to know thanks

Comment: If you start with qemu or bochs the source code for the virtual card would be there so you could figure out both from the register spec and an implementation of that register spec.  (and you dont do any damage to your video card nor monitor).

Comment: Hmmm this is coming back to me slowly now, for the compatible modes the address space may actually be common/fixed like the uarts.  0xA0000 and 0xB0000 perhaps address spaces.

Comment: Physical memory not virtual.

Comment: The only reliable way to access a video card without the BIOS is signing an NDA with the vendor, unfortunately. I always advise going for the Intel GFX cards because: 1) The [Programming Reference Manuals](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/documentation/hardware-specification-prms) are online and you can grasp the complexity 2) If you have an Intel CPU you also have an Intel graphic card these days.

Comment: You can "borrow" some code from open source linux drivers. Or better use BIOS just to switch to graphics mode, read linear framebuffer address from PCI configuration space and write directly to memory (you would need to use either unreal mode or protected mode).

Comment: @Margaret Bloom *"The only reliable way to access a video card without the BIOS is signing an NDA with the vendor"* What do you mean by that? You mean I have to ask the creator of the video card to tell me how the video card can be accessed, and I should promise the creator that I will not give the details to anyone :)?

Comment: @Steve, Exactly! :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### Introduction

Graphics cards are a very complex topic, I'm confident in saying that they are the *most* complex subsystem you'll find on a PC.
If you ever found yourself lost programming an [XHCI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Host_Controller_Interface) (USB 3.0) or an old [RTL8239A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTL8139) network interface card then be prepared because this is much more complex.

Graphics controllers are the products of a very competitive marketing - [rarely a vendor opens the specifications](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2911459/why-nvidia-graphics-cards-are-the-worst-for-open-source-but-the-best-for-linux-gaming.html) and when it does, it gives an intentionally poor support.
If you add that the hardware itself deals with: [codecs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_codec), [audio (yes, audio streams too)](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/standards/high-definition-audio-specification.html), [3D *programmable* pipelines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_pipeline), [video signals and video outputs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_video_connectors), surface formats, media formats, [DMA and memory remapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_address_remapping_table) then you can see that it is not an easy task to program a video card.

The better approach, in my opinion, is to "retrace the history" of the video cards.
Start from the [MDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Monochrome_Display_Adapter) then move to [CGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_Graphics_Adapter) then [EGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enhanced_Graphics_Adapter) and finally to [VGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_Graphics_Array).

The VGA legacy is still supported, the specifications can be found [here](http://www.osdever.net/FreeVGA/vga/vga.htm) or in the first part of [this PDF](https://01.org/sites/default/files/documentation/intel-gfx-prm-osrc-hsw-display.pdf) from Intel.
You can program the VGA without the BIOS "easily" - meaning that it is an already well-known and documented hardware architecture (but not necessarily easy to configure).
I don't remember if the previous adapters were subsets of the VGA or not, if not they aren't supported anymore probably.
You can try with a virtual machine or an emulator.

When you are satisfied with the VGA you can move to the [SVGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_video_graphics_array).
Here come the troubles: as Wikipedia confirms, the VGA was the last truly standardised video card/adapter interface:

> Unlike VGA—a purely IBM-defined standard—Super VGA was never formally defined.

The organisation VESA standardised a BIOS API called [Video BIOS Extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VESA_BIOS_Extensions) to allow the use of SVGA cards to driverless OSes but that's not what you were looking for.
You can try reverse engineering a VBE BIOS but I think it will be a nightmare - a senseless stream of writes to IO ports and MMIOs.
Making sense of tenths of configuration registers without any reference is almost impossible.

Note that we are still talking about 1998 technology up to this point.
After the VESA VBE effort, no more standard interfaces have been published - the only reliable way to program a video card with less than 20 years is by signing an NDA with its vendor.

Luckily, recently (actually, not anymore), Intel entered the market with its Intel GFX (a.k.a. Intel HD Graphics) cards.
Intel never aimed to manufacture top-of-the-notch video cards, not even closely - so they can be open about their architecture since that's not their core business.
The result is this marvellous set of [Programming Reference Manuals](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/documentation/hardware-specification-prms) that describe the functionality of their video cards.
Complete with (traditionalistic) minimal information to program them.

In general, hobbyists stops before this point (at the SVGA checkpoint), because the hardware has become very complex and the efforts very huge.
For example, my Haswell integrated video card is documented with 17 PDFs of about 250 pages each (on average).
The display part is documented in a PDF on its own, the framebuffer has disappeared in favour of *Display surface* and the display part alone of the hardware is this:

[image: Intel Graphic Display Engine]

While this may not be very comprehensible, it should suffice to get an idea of the numerous technology that a programmer must understand before programming a modern video card.

You can surely take a look at the Linux source code but beware that the Linux kernel is no usually of immediate understanding even for simple controllers - it is not a toy OS, it is a real OS with its own API and interface that must fit the hardware interface (actually the other way around).
Furthermore, only the Intel and AMD video drivers are really open source, the others are either proprietary or just a bunch of undocumented code.

### Brief outline of common VGA modes programming

If you just want to program the VGA (a very respectable task indeed!) you can start by [setting the video modes](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0069.htm) 03h (text mode) or 13h (graphics mode).

**Video mode 03h**
The frame buffer is at 0b8000h (physical address), usually accessed as 0b800h:0000h as it is handy to have a zero offset.
The screen is made up of 80x25 characters, each characters occupy a word (16-bit) in the frame buffer.
The low byte is the character code - the character map used will associate a [glyph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glyph) to a code (e.g. 41h to A).
The high order byte is the attribute byte - the low nibble is the foreground colour, the high nibble is the background colour.
More information can be found in the EGA/CGA/VGA links above.

**Video mode 13h**
It is a graphical mode with 320x200 pixel, the frame buffer is at 0a0000h (physical address) usually accessed as 0a000h:0000h for the same reason of above.
Each pixel is a single byte, the value of the byte selects the colour of the pixel.
The default palette can be changed by programming the DAC registers (3c7h, 3c8h, 3c9h for the VGA adapter).

### Answers

> A graphics card has two modes: a text mode, and a graphics mode.

Not necessarily, today this distinction may not exist anymore.
The MDA had only a text mode.
EGA, CGA and VGA and SVGA had both.

The modern approach is to draw the text, however during boot or during particular situations (e.g. [BSOD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Screen_of_Death)) a basic video driver in text mode is used.
This driver probably uses a BIOS service since the video driver may not be available/reliable.

> You can write data to a graphics cards using BIOS

Up to the SVGA era, then BIOS support was discontinued.

> How do I know what is the base address of the video memory of the graphics card, is this done by probing the PCI bus to get the base address, or is the base address fixed (just like the COM ports base addresses is fixed for example)?

Video cards have been connected through the history to the ISA, PCI, AGP and PCIe buses.
Only the ISA bus wasn't configurable (at least not from the beginning), the others had configurable BARs (Base Address Registers) per function (the smallest addressable entity in the PCI bus).

In order to get the base address of the MMIO registers of a video card the PCI or PCIe bus [must be enumerated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_configuration_space) and the standard registers in the configuration space must be read/set.

Dealing with PCIe is not as easy as dealing with PCI.

Note that not even the UARTs have a fixed address, they are configured by default to map to the legacy (3f8h, 2f8h, 3e8h and 2e8h) addresses but the hardware was (is?) in a [SuperIO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_I/O) chip behind a PCI-to-LPC bridge that emulated a PCI-to-ISA bridge.
With the advent of the Intel platform hub architecture (i.e. the death of the north and south bridge) the SuperIO chip eventually made it into the [PCH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Controller_Hub) or moved behind the [SPI controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface_Bus).

> Are all graphics cards accessed in the same way, or do I have to create device drivers for all available graphics cards?

Each graphic card is a beautiful vicious creature on its own.
A device driver is needed for each model.
Some driver can be reused for a whole family of models but this is not true in general.

Comment: *"I don't remember if the previous adapters were subsets of the VGA or not."* The EGA was largely a subset of the VGA. Or, said more correctly, VGA was a superset of EGA. That doesn't mean it'll be supported by modern machines (or emulators), though. Almost everything assumes VGA as a baseline, and will try to use VGA modes, which may damage (or at the very least, won't work on) an EGA card. Emulators of vintage systems are, of course, a different story.