# Get EDID info in C (UEFI): read the ES:DI register?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, operating-system, uefi

I am Developing an OS, I wants to get EDID from monitor, I am found some asm code (https://wiki.osdev.org/EDID) to get edid in ES:DI registers,

```
mov ax,     0x4f15
mov bl,     0x01
xor cx,     cx
xor dx,     dx
int         0x10
;AL = 0x4F if function supported
;AH = status (0 is success, 1 is fail)
;ES:DI contains the EDID
```

How can I get AL, AH, and ES:DI values in C File?

**Actually I am developing an 64 bit UEFI OS**

```
LoadGDT:   
    lgdt [rdi]
    mov ax, 0x10 
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax
    mov ss, ax
    pop rdi
    mov rax, 0x08
    push rax
    push rdi
    retfq
GLOBAL LoadGDT
```

I am able to run these above asm code and get it in c using Global Functions in C,

Comment: It's unlikely, but possible, that you are actually using a C compiler that is targeting a 16-bit real-mode environment. Can you please confirm that you indeed understand that the assembly code is for real-mode and that your C compiler can correctly handle that?

Comment: Yes, I am using gcc

Comment: @VapourDev Which variant of gcc are you using?  Are you programming in real mode?

Comment: or Any other ways to read EDID

Comment: If you state that you develop in C, why [tag:c++]?

Comment: @Scheff C and c++ are very similar and c can be externed by c++

Comment: Well, please, feel free to roll-back my tag-edit. (Maybe, it cannot hurt to [edit] a note in why you have chosen the [tag:c++] while talking about C. Otherwise, somebody else might have similar concerns like me.)

Comment: No Problem _____

Comment: Gcc can't really handle 16-bit code. It will just add override prefixes and anyway you can't call BIOS interrupt services from real/long-mode because the IDT (and the segmentation assumed by the BIOS code) is different. **Since you are using UEFI, just use the `EFI_EDID_DISCOVERED_PROTOCOL` interface**.

Comment: Yes, I found this now https://blog.fpmurphy.com/2012/09/accessing-edid-information-from-uefi-shell.html

Comment: @MargaretBloom: I updated the title to try to resolve the XY problem; I think you can post that comment as an answer now if there isn't a duplicate about UEFI ways of doing it.

Comment: @PeterCordes It seems there are no duplicates. I see if I can craft a simple example in UEFI, otherwise it would be too much of a useless answer.

Comment: @MargaretBloom: If you don't want to take the time for that, simply pointing out that most https://osdev.org/ pages are about legacy 16-bit BIOS interfaces / IBM-PC hardware, and how UEFI is totally different, would be a good answer.  And a possible useful duplicate for future questions about other interfaces, not specifically EDID.  Of course, we don't currently get a lot of questions where the answer is "that's legacy BIOS stuff, use the totally different UEFI interface."

Comment: Hello , Anyone have Idea about it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67489025/how-can-i-write-own-video-driver-for-my-os

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That page on [osdev.org](https://osdev.org/) contains code intended to be run when the CPU is in 16-bit real mode.
You can tell not only from the registers involved but also from the fact that `int 10h` is used.
[This is a well-known BIOS interrupt service](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int-10.htm) that is written in 16-bit real-mode code.

If you target UEFI, then your bootloader is actually an *UEFI application*, which is a PE32(+) image.
If the CPU is 64-bit capable, the firmware will switch into long mode (64-bit mode) and load your bootloader.
Otherwise, it will switch into protected mode (32-bit mode).
In any case, real mode is never used in UEFI.

You can call 16-bit code from protected/long mode with the use of a 16-bit code segment in the GDT/LDT but you cannot call real-mode code (i.e. code written to work with the real-mode segmentation) because segmentation works completely different between the modes.
Plus, in real mode the interrupts are dispatched through the IVT and not the IDT, you would need to get the original entry-point for interrupt 10h.

## UEFI protocol `EFI_EDID_DISCOVERED_PROTOCOL`

Luckily, UEFI has a replacement for most basic services offered by the legacy BIOS interface.
In this case, you can use the `EFI_EDID_DISCOVERED_PROTOCOL` and eventually apply any override from the platform firmware with the use of `EFI_EDID_OVERRIDE_PROTOCOL`.

The `EFI_EDID_DISCOVERED_PROTOCOL` is straightforward to use, it's just a *(Size, Data)* pair.

```
typedef struct _EFI_EDID_DISCOVERED_PROTOCOL {
    UINT32   SizeOfEdid;
    UINT8   *Edid;
} EFI_EDID_DISCOVERED_PROTOCOL;
```

(from [gnu-efi](https://github.com/vathpela/gnu-efi/blob/3e4d5c79905afcd815b0beb3dcfe2dfae5b3e6dd/inc/efiprot.h#L1005))

The format of the buffer `Edid` can be found in the VESA specification or even on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Display_Identification_Data).

As an example, I wrote a simple UEFI application with *gnu-efi* and  *x64_64-w64-mingw32* (a version of GCC and tools that target PEs).
I avoided using `uefilib.h` in order to use gnu-efi just for the definition of the structures related to EUFI.

The code **sucks**, it assumes at most 10 handles support the EDID protocol and I wrote only a partial structure for the EDID data (because I got bored).
But this should be enough the get the idea.

**NOTE That my VM didn't return any EDID information, so the code is not completely tested!**

```
#include <efi.h>

//You are better off using this lib
//#include <efilib.h>

EFI_GUID gEfiEdidDiscoveredProtocolGuid = EFI_EDID_DISCOVERED_PROTOCOL_GUID;
EFI_SYSTEM_TABLE* gST = NULL;

typedef struct _EDID14 {
    UINT8 Signature[8];
    UINT16 ManufacturerID;
    UINT16 ManufacturerCode;
    UINT32 Serial;
    UINT8 Week;
    UINT8 Year;
    UINT8 Major;
    UINT8 Minor;
    UINT32 InputParams;
    UINT8 HSize;
    UINT8 VSize;
    UINT8 Gamma;
    
    //...Omitted...
} EDID14_RAW;

VOID Print(CHAR16* string)
{
    gST->ConOut->OutputString(gST->ConOut, string);
}

VOID PrintHex(UINT64 number)
{
    CHAR16* digits = L"0123456789abcdef";
    CHAR16 buffer[2] = {0, 0};
    
    for (INTN i = 64-4; i >= 0; i-=4)
    {
        buffer[0] = digits[(number >> i) & 0xf];
        Print(buffer);
    }   
}

VOID PrintDec(UINT64 number)
{
    CHAR16 buffer[21] = {0};
    UINTN i = 19;
    
    do
    {
        buffer[i--] = L'0' + (number % 10);
        number = number / 10;
    }
    while (number && i >= 0);
    
    Print(buffer + i + 1);
}


#define MANUFACTURER_DECODE_LETTER(x)  ( L'A' + ( (x) & 0x1f ) - 1 )


EFI_STATUS efi_main(EFI_HANDLE ImageHandle, EFI_SYSTEM_TABLE* SystemTable)
{
    EFI_STATUS Status = EFI_SUCCESS;
    EFI_HANDLE EDIDHandles[10];
    UINTN Size = sizeof(EFI_HANDLE) * 10;
    EFI_EDID_DISCOVERED_PROTOCOL* EDID;
     
    gST = SystemTable;
    
    if ( EFI_ERROR( (Status = SystemTable->BootServices->LocateHandle(ByProtocol, &gEfiEdidDiscoveredProtocolGuid, NULL, &Size, EDIDHandles)) ) )
    {
        Print(L"Failed to get EDID handles: "); PrintHex(Status); Print(L"\r\n");
        return Status;
    }

    for (INTN i = 0; i < Size/sizeof(EFI_HANDLE); i++)
    {
        if (EFI_ERROR( (SystemTable->BootServices->OpenProtocol(
            EDIDHandles[i], &gEfiEdidDiscoveredProtocolGuid, (VOID**)&EDID, ImageHandle, NULL, EFI_OPEN_PROTOCOL_GET_PROTOCOL)) ) )
        {
            Print(L"Failed to get EDID info for handle "); PrintDec(i); Print(L": "); PrintHex(Status); Print(L"\r\n");
            return Status;
        }
        
        if (EDID->SizeOfEdid == 0 || EDID->Edid == NULL)
        {
            Print(L"No EDID data for handle "); PrintDec(i); Print(L"\r\n");
            continue;
        }
        
        /*
            THIS CODE IS NOT TESTED!
            ! ! !   D O   N O T   U S E  ! ! !
        */
        EDID14_RAW* EdidData = (EDID14_RAW*)EDID->Edid;
        
        CHAR16 Manufacturer[4] = {0};
        Manufacturer[0] = MANUFACTURER_DECODE_LETTER(EdidData->ManufacturerID >> 10);
        Manufacturer[1] = MANUFACTURER_DECODE_LETTER(EdidData->ManufacturerID >> 5);
        Manufacturer[2] = MANUFACTURER_DECODE_LETTER(EdidData->ManufacturerID);
        Print(L"Manufacturer ID: "); Print(Manufacturer); Print(L"\r\n");
        Print(L"Resolution: "); PrintDec(EdidData->HSize); Print(L"X"); PrintDec(EdidData->VSize); Print(L"\r\n");
        
    }
    return Status;
}
```

## ACPI

If you don't want to use these UEFI protocols you can use ACPI. Each display output device has a `_DDC` method that is documented in the ACPI specification and can be used to return the EDID data (either as a buffer of 128 or 256 bytes).
This method is conceptually simple but in practice it requires writing a full-blown ACPI parser (including the AML VM) which is a lot of work.
However, ACPI is necessary for modern OSes and so you can use it, later on, to get the EDID data without having to worry about UEFI protocols.

Comment: Full working example available at https://github.com/fpmurphy/UEFI-Utilities-2019/blob/master/MyApps/ShowEDID/

Comment: @fpmurphy I am getting error, [EDID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67847762/reading-edid-with-gnuefi-protocols)

Comment: @user16028858.  Without telling us what error you are getting, how do you expect anybody to help you?  Be specific.   You are also pointing to a different question.

Comment: @fmurphy Abe Niklune Sela Suar!